# How does quantity of keys inside one hash slot influence on the performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sorting, caching, redis, amazon-elasticache

Adding different keys to the same slot using hash tags is possible. But which influence on the performance does it make?

PS:
According to the @Quassnoi answer - The threshold for storing hash values as listpack is set by the variable hash-max-listpack-entries (512 by default). What will happen if we increase this size to 2k+ and write 2k of keys using hash tags into the single hash slot inside one shard and one node? Which influence on the performance it will make?

Comment: You have four questions here, of which only #2 is objective answerable (and is a good question). Can you please edit your post and only leave one question? Thank you!

Comment: @Quassnoi, sure. I left only questions related to performance

Comment: I just realized that I might have completely misunderstood your question. Are you asking about the hash data structure (`HSET` and its friends) or about the clustering feature?

Comment: @Quassnoi I think both of them. I have added some details to the PS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "and write 2k of keys using hash tags into the single hash slot": I'm having trouble understanding what it is you're asking about. When you write a hash value, however long, you always write it into a single key. Writing 2k worth of keys using the same tag would result in 2k worth of hash values, which will all end up on a single shard. The length of every individual value that you're writing has absolutely no bearing on this fact.

Answer (score 0):

> Which data structure does Redis use for slots with a few keys to optimize read and write operations? Is it a linked list or some kind of sorted tree?

Previous versions of Redis used ziplist (an interleaved list of keys and values). To retrieve a value, you just scan the whole list. It's not a linked list proper, but each value does hold the length of the previous entry, so scanning backwards is efficient as well.

Current versions use [listpack](https://github.com/antirez/listpack/blob/master/listpack.md), which uses the same idea, but makes some changes to the internal representations of the values to improve performance.

The threshold for storing hash values as listpack is set by the variable [`hash-max-listpack-entries`](https://redis.io/docs/management/optimization/memory-optimization/) (512 by default).